# Django-inplaceedit and tinyMCE not staying in edit mode and I am unable to figure out how to debug

Tags: django, tinymce, django-inplaceedit

When I edit a plain text item using the tinyMCE adaptor things work good, but after that the text is uneditable via inplaceedit.

For example if I start with:

```
some unformatted text
```

then I can double click and edit it, but if it saves with any kind of markup for example:

```
<p>some unformatted <em>text</em></p>
```

then I can no longer double click and edit it. Even more strange, if I go to my template and add change  `{% inplace_edit "item.about_story" adaptor="tiny" %}`  to  `{% inplace_edit "item.about_story" | safe adaptor="tiny" %}`  - then my page renders unformatted text with markup but it is also then stuck in the tinyMCE edit mode.

My project is located here for reference:
https://github.com/originalsurfmex/addition_interiors_project

Model name:  `class About` 
 View name:  `class AboutDetail` 
 Template name:  `about_list.html`

My settings file:
https://github.com/originalsurfmex/addition_interiors_project/blob/master/addition_interiors_project/settings.py

My models file:
https://github.com/originalsurfmex/addition_interiors_project/blob/master/frontpage/models.py

My views file:
https://github.com/originalsurfmex/addition_interiors_project/blob/master/frontpage/views.py

My template:
https://github.com/originalsurfmex/addition_interiors_project/blob/master/frontpage/templates/frontpage/about_list.html

```
virtualenvironment:
    python 3.3
    django 1.6
    django-inplaceedit-extra-fields==0.5.0
    django-inplaceedit==1.3.0
    django-grappelli==2.5.2
    django-filebrowser==3.5.4
```